# Chrome not opening in the server with Windows service developed in C# with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, windows-services

Below is my Code it is working fine in the debug mode and installed service in my laptop it working ,But if i installed same service in the server it is not opening the chrome and not throwing any error also.

```
ChromeDriverService driverS = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverS.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            driverS.Port = 4444;
            ChromeOptions driverO = new ChromeOptions();
         
            // driverO.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;
            driverO.Proxy = new Proxy { Kind = ProxyKind.Direct };
     

            string WPSPortalLink = "www.google.com";
            log.Info("Opening chrome");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(driverS, driverO);

            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(WPSPortalLink);
            log.Info("Link Opened");
```

Comment: Windows services and UI/desktop interaction is difficult. Search a little about it. See this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177588/running-an-exe-from-windows-service-that-interacts-the-the-users-desktop)

Comment: For 1 week it is working fine ,but after patch updates in the server it is not working again